# How to Read and Write integers to a file

Tags: c, file, file-io

The thing is that im trying to read some integers to know the levels of the game I have already passed through, then I want to put the integer of the current level to one if t is not already. It creates the file but doesn't write anything. Anyone know why?   Now, it does it the first time when creating it with printf but when reading it gives status access violation.

```
void SaveGame(void)
{
  FILE *pFile = fopen("SavedData.txt","rb");
  int MyArray[8] = {0};

  if(pFile)
  {
    fscanf(pFile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" , MyArray[0], MyArray[1], MyArray[2], MyArray[3], MyArray[4], MyArray[5], MyArray[6], MyArray[7]);
    fclose(pFile);
  }

  if(MyArray[Current] == 0)
    MyArray[Current] = 1;

  pFile = fopen("SavedData.txt", "wb");

  if(pFile)
  {
    fprintf(pFile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" , MyArray[0], MyArray[1], MyArray[2], MyArray[3], MyArray[4], MyArray[5], MyArray[6], MyArray[7]);
    fclose(pFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(MyArray[Current] = 0)` you need to use `==`.

Comment: You need to pass the file handle to `feof` ... `feof(pFile);`

Comment: Your write loop is infinite. I.e., it's up to *you* to determine where the file ends.

Comment: `while (!feof(pFile))` in the read-loop is probably worse than `while (!feof)`

Comment: and now, it does it the first time when creating it with printf but when reading it gives status acces violation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want something like this (untested) :

```
#define SAVE_FILE "SavedData.txt"
#define NUMS_SIZE 8

void SaveGame() {
  FILE *f;

  f = fopen(SAVE_FILE, "r");
  if (!f) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't open save file for reading.\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  int nums[NUMS_SIZE] = {0};
  int n, i = 0;
  while (fscanf(f, "%d", &n) == 1) {
    if (i >= NUMS_SIZE) break;
    nums[i++] = n;
  }
  fclose(f);

  f = fopen(SAVE_FILE, "w");
  if (!f) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can't open save file for writing.\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  int j = 0;
  if (i > 0) fprintf("%d", nums[0]);
  for (j = 1; j < i; ++j)
    fprintf(" %d", nums[j]);
  fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Output loop should end at the previous value of `i`, not at `NUMS_SIZE`. Input loop should stop before overflowing the bounds of `nums`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Agreed. Updated. Although it actually depends on how the OP wants it. I imagined the file to have 8 zeros in it, but it's best to check.

Comment: True, he might want to write 8 numbers even if the input was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you read a file.

For starters if it is a text file, open with mode `"r"`, not `"rb"`.

When you do a read operation you should check to see whether the read operation suceeded or failed. You don't do `feof` instead.  There is a lot of code out there that does `feof` and most of it is wrong. Be wary when copying off internet code samples.

Also, it's a great idea to read the documentation for any standard function you use. You may learn things about the function that you didn't know. For example, `fscanf` returns how many items were successfully read.

So in your reading loop, either check that `fscanf` returns 8 (or loop 8 times as ooga suggested, checking for `1` each time).  Don't check `feof` during the loop.

Once the read fails, THEN you have the option to do `feof` to find out why the read failed, if you care to know. It could have fail because you hit the end of file (`feof`), or because of a device error (`ferror`), or because the file had words in it instead of numbers.

When you do the writing part, make sure you only write numbers which were successfully read.