# Status access violation when reading from file C

Tags: c, file, file-io

The thing is that im trying to read some integers to know the levels of the game I have already passed through, then I want to put the integer of the current level to one if t is not already. It creates the file but doesnt write anything. Anyone knows why?? - It does it the first time when creating it with printf but when reading it gives status acces violation

```
void SaveGame(void)
{
  FILE *pFile = fopen("SavedData.txt","rb");
  int MyArray[8] = {0};

  if(pFile)
  {
    fscanf(pFile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" , MyArray[0], MyArray[1], MyArray[2], MyArray[3], MyArray[4], MyArray[5], MyArray[6], MyArray[7]);
    fclose(pFile);
  }

  if(MyArray[Current] == 0)
    MyArray[Current] = 1;

  pFile = fopen("SavedData.txt", "wb");

  if(pFile)
  {
    fprintf(pFile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" , MyArray[0], MyArray[1], MyArray[2], MyArray[3], MyArray[4], MyArray[5], MyArray[6], MyArray[7]);
    fclose(pFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should check the 1st `fclose(pFile);` return value.

Comment: `MyArray[0]` should be `&MyArray[0]` or `MyArray+0` in `scanf` parameters. Same goes for every other index.

Comment: Are you asking for all warnings? Use `-Wall -Wextra`. Then handle all warnings properly. Many compilers can actually check various format strings.

Comment: This is strikingly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025022/how-to-read-and-write-integers-to-a-file-c

Answer (score 0):

All the elements of `MyArray` have been initialized to `0`.

By using,

```
fscanf(pFile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" , MyArray[0], MyArray[1], MyArray[2], MyArray[3], MyArray[4], MyArray[5], MyArray[6], MyArray[7]);
```

You are in essence, calling,

```
fscanf(pFile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Change that line to:

```
fscanf(pFile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d" , &MyArray[0], &MyArray[1], &MyArray[2], &MyArray[3], &MyArray[4], &MyArray[5], &MyArray[6], &MyArray[7]);
```